# alignItems: baseline not working on Android

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to have a phrase, which has different font-sizes all aligned on bottom and so, I have done the following:

```
<View style={styles.header}>
  <TextCustomized style={styles.balance} text="você tem" />
  <TextCustomized style={styles.number} text=" R$" />
  <TextCustomized style={styles.integer} text="100" />
  <TextCustomized style={styles.number} text=",00" />
  <TextCustomized style={styles.balance} text=" de saldo" />
</View>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  header: {
   flexDirection: 'row',
   alignItems: 'baseline',
   justifyContent: 'center',
   paddingTop: 10,
   borderBottomWidth: 1,
   borderBottomColor: '#e1e1e1',
   paddingBottom: 10,
 },
 balance: {
   fontSize: 14
 },
 number: {
  fontSize: 18,
  color: '#0778e4',
  fontWeight: 'bold',
 },
 integer: {
   fontSize: 30,
   color: '#0778e4',
   fontWeight: "800",
   lineHeight: 30,
 },
})
```

It works perfectly on iOS, but on Android it doesn`t work as it should, as you can see on this PS.

[image]

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Try wrapping the 5 `TextCustomized` elements into a `Text`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a workaround, you can wrap the text you want aligned baseline into a `Text` element. The `alignItems: baseline` in the parent will be unnecessary at that point. Something like this should work:

```
<View style={styles.header}>
  <Text>
    <TextCustomized style={styles.balance} text="você tem" />
    <TextCustomized style={styles.number} text=" R$" />
    <TextCustomized style={styles.integer} text="100" />
    <TextCustomized style={styles.number} text=",00" />
    <TextCustomized style={styles.balance} text=" de saldo" />
  </Text>
</View>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  header: {
   flexDirection: 'row',
   justifyContent: 'center',
   paddingTop: 10,
   borderBottomWidth: 1,
   borderBottomColor: '#e1e1e1',
   paddingBottom: 10,
 },
 balance: {
   fontSize: 14
 },
 number: {
  fontSize: 18,
  color: '#0778e4',
  fontWeight: 'bold',
 },
 integer: {
   fontSize: 30,
   color: '#0778e4',
   fontWeight: "800",
   lineHeight: 30,
 }
});
```

[image: React Native Align Baseline Android]